# Calling functions from different js files using webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

How to call a function from a different js file using webpack like this?

module1.js:

```
require('./module2.js');
var myObject = {};
myObject.doSomething = function(){
    //some task
    actions.activity();
};
```

module2.js:

```
var actions = {};
actions.activity = function(){
    document.getElementsByTagName('p').innerHTML = "Loaded by webpack!"
};
module.exports = actions;
```

index.html:

```
<button onclick="myObject.doSomething();">Click here</button>
<p></p>
<script type="text/javascript" src = 'bin/bundle.js'></script>
```

webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/module1.js',
    output: {
        path: './bin',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    }
}
```

After I run webpack command, it throws an error and I am unable to generate bundle.js

Comment: exporting file seems to be fine. Issue may be with webpack configuration

Comment: please show what is the error

Comment: ERROR in ./src/module2.js
Module parse failed: /var/www/html/webpack/practice/3/src/module2.js Unexpected token (2:8)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (2:8)